# Rename Subscription database in merge replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-replication, merge-replication

I want to rename a subscription database in merge replication. All the subscriptions are synchronized properly.

IS it possible to rename one of the subscription database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can

1. Take backup of your database.
2. Stop merge agent on the publisher.
3. Rename the database.
4. update db_name field in sysmergesubscriptions table bot on Subscriber as well as publisher
5. Start the merge agent.

sample query :

```
 update sysmergesubscriptions set db_name='YourDBName'
 where subscriber_server='YourSubscriber'
```